# OpenGL Adding More Data to VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo

Is it possible to add more data to a VBO without blowing away the old contents. Basically is there a way to resize the VBO while keeping the old contents?

For example, lets say I interleaved some color(CrCgCb) and position(PxPy) data in a VBO to represent a square using two triangles, such that a abstract representation of memory in the VBO looked like:

```
 [P1x,P1y,C1r,C1g,C1b,P2x,P2y,C2r,C2g,C2b,P3x,P3y,C3r,C3g,C3b,P4x,P4y,C4r,C4g,C4b,P5x,P5y,C5r,C5g,C5b,P6x,P6y,C6r,C6g,C6b]
```

Now some event transpires and all of a sudden another square is born and I want to place it in the same VBO such that the data now looks like:

```
[P1x,P1y,C1r,C1g,C1b,P2x,P2y,C2r,C2g,C2b,P3x,P3y,C3r,C3g,C3b,P4x,P4y,C4r,C4g,C4b,P5x,P5y,C5r,C5g,C5b,P6x,P6y,C6r,C6g,C6b,P7x,P7y,C7r,C7g,C7b,P8x,P8y,C8r,C8g,C8b,P9x,P9y,C9r,C9g,C9b,P10x,P10y,C10r,C10g,C10b,P11x,P11y,C11r,C11g,C11b,P12x,P12y,C12r,C12g,C12b]
```

To place the first batch of data I would do this:

```
  GLuint vbo;
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  float verticies[6 * 2 + 6 * 3] = ...;
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Now to get the second square in there I normally would do something as follows:

```
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  float verticies[12 * 2 + 12 * 3] = ...;
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

How do you do this without having to call `glDeleteBuffers()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for glBufferSubData. This can not resize the buffer, but can change data in an existing buffer. Just make sure your buffer is big enough from the beginning. A common pattern is to initialize the buffer with BufferData and a null pointer to a certain size and then change only parts of it with BufferSubData.

Comment: Thank for the input, however I am already aware of that function. The reason it does not work for me is because I have a very dynamic system and I have memory constraints. I cant resize the VBO to some large size and then run some fragmentation algorithm. I guess my best bet is to just maintain a vector and dynamically resize that. Then when time comes keep track of which objects to draw. Load the VBO with all data and then to glDrawArays use start and count variables. Not desired but if this is my only option then I will go with it.

Comment: Yes, that's your only option. Dealing with stuff like that is what make game engines valuable. You have to manage your own memory. Often the easiest algorithm is good enough though. Pools of 1mb each, grow like a stack and recycle empty pools.